# Process.Start(...) throws "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c#, process, command-prompt

For immediate registry change without restarting the computer i found out that using

```
cmd.exe /c taskkill.exe /f /im explorer.exe & explorer.exe
```

is exactly doing what i want.

I read that you can't use files like `cmd.exe` without their whole path because they don't have a **PATH** value and don't exist in the **System32** folder.

```
const string explorer = @"C:\Windows\explorer.exe";
string taskkill = "", commandprompt = "";
var task1 = Task.Run(() =>
    taskkill = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Windows\WinSxS", "*microsoft-windows-taskkill_*")[0] + @"\taskkill.exe");
var task2 = Task.Run(() =>
    commandprompt = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Windows\WinSxS", "*microsoft-windows-commandprompt_*")[0] + @"\cmd.exe");

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
Process.Start(string.Format($"{commandprompt} /c {taskkill} /f /im {explorer} & {explorer}"));
```

But running this piece of code throws

```
"The system cannot find the file specified"
```

Would appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem!

**EDIT #1**:

```
Process.Start(commandprompt, string.Format($"/c {taskkill} /f /im {explorer} & {explorer}"));
```

by changing the code as answered, the command-prompt opens only for a second ans says something like "*The request is invalid*" and after that the explorer window opens.

Comment: Don't know if there are other issues, but main one is if you want run Process.Start with arguments - you have to pass two parameters: file name and arguments. So in your case first is `commandprompt` and second is all the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to call cmd.exe /c, you should be able to run taskkill.exe directly.

This works on my machine (windows 10).Do you need to search for the files every time?  I think for a simple utility app, having the paths hard coded should be fine.

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    Verb = "runas",
    Arguments = "/f /im explorer.exe",
    FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\taskkill.exe"
};
var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    Verb = "runas",
    FileName = @"C:\windows\explorer.exe"
};
process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
process.Start();
```

Comment: The reason for searching the files is that i didn't knew they were located in **system32** too, and the directory i searched in is totally userspecific so you can't hardcode it. But thank you it works fine now!

Comment: I don't think explorer and task kill should be user specific, maybe os specific.  Aren't the WinSxS folder used for DEP and windows update?  In any case, glad it worked for you.

Comment: yes it's something like a "Component Store" and safes some systemfiles for kind of backup

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [the two-argument overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Process.Start` if you want to pass command-line parameters.